# Accessing Child.plist of Settings.bundle in iPhone application - How?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, settings.bundle

I am facing a problem in accessing Settings.bundle.

Let me explain what exactly I am doing.

1. Any kind of new Project Template from File ( Under iPhone OS ) - preferable View based.
2. Now Right click on your project / Resources group.
3. Select Add / New File
4. Under iPhone Os - resource - Settings Bundle.
5. Name it as strictly "Settings.bundle"

Now The very important steps.

1. Expand Settings.bundle in your project.
2. Click on Root.plist
3. In Editor - Expand Preference Specifiers
4. Remove Item 2, Item 3, Item 4
5. Select Item 1 & copy & Past it.
6. Edit Item 2' type ( Item 1's copy )
7. Set **PSChildPaneSpecifier** as type ( of item'2 )
8. Set Title as you wish.
9. Add a new Key value pair to this ( item 2 ) dictionary.
10. Set Key = "File" & String = "FontSettings"

Now In above steps, I have specified " I need a child pane for settings " 
& Child Pane settings will be loaded from **FontSettings.plist**

Ok. Further Steps.

1. Now, Right click on your Settings.bundle / en.lproj ( Just because we need to add another plist file under settings.bundle.
2. Add / New File - Under Mac OS x - Choose Other -> Property List
3. Name as **FontSettings.plist**

For just verification that settings.bundle contains that file or not.

1. Open your project in finder.
2. Right click on **Settings.bundle**
3. Click on show package contents.
4. If it shows **FontSettings.plist** in package contents, Then it's perfect till now.

Now, For FontSettings.plist

1. Open Root.plist under settings.bundle.
2. Copy Stringtable, PreferenceSpecifiers to the FontSettings.plist
3. Now in **FontSettings.plist** - Add settings as you wish.

Check in simulator.

1. Run program & tap on button. ( To terminate app. )
2. Go to settings.
3. Open Your Project Settings
4. You can go to child pane.

---

Till now, I believe I have followed the correct steps.

The problem that I am facing is here now.

If there is just a single **Root.plist**, we can directly access

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"fName"]
```

Like above.

But the question is "How to access - child pane settings ? "

I have tried following way

```
NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *path=[str stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FontSettings.plist"];
NSDictionary *dFor=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

But the problem in above code is "It's just giving me the same default value every time, even after - changing the values from settings of iPhone - settings.

What should I do for Accessing Child.plist settings? (that user has set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You access child pane settings exactly like the root settings. There's no difference between hierarchies in accessing the user defaults.

For instance, if a PSToggleSwitchSpecifier in FontSettings.plist has `Key` being `isBold`, then you'll access this setting with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isBold"]
```

Comment: As a note for anyone coming across this, most likely your issue if it appears that the values are not accessible is that __default values are read as nil__.